# Add value to List inside Map<String, List> in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Is there a better way in Java 8 to add a value to a List inside of a Map?

In java 7 i would write:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> myMap = new HashMap<>();
...
if (!myMap.containsKey(MY_KEY)) {
    myMap.put(MY_KEY, new ArrayList<>());
}
myMap.get(MY_KEY).add(value);
```

Comment: What do you mean "better"?

Comment: @Andremoniy look at the answer below to understand "better".

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You should use the method [`Map::computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) to create or get the `List`:

```
myMap.computeIfAbsent(MY_KEY, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value);
```